# Regarding fltk installation

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, fltk

I am new to c++ and overall programming. I tried reading one book by Bjarne Stroustrup he mentioned in the very first chapter to first install fltk and write the code. Should I install fltk or use online compiler. If I should install fltk then please tell how as I am unable to do so. Thank you.

I tried downloading and unzipping the fltk file two times. It got unzipped but the fltk.snl file is getting opened by visual studios but othing is happening since I am unable to run c++ code in VS.

Comment: The first thing you need to do in Visual Studio when the `fltk.sln` file (bundled with FLTK 1.3.x) is opened is to select the "Build" menu and then "Build Solution". If this doesn't work (missing C++ compiler?) you may need to review your Visual Studio installation. ISTR that you need to select "C++" as a separate option and something similar to "Build Desktop Applications".
Please tell us also which VS version you installed and for completeness which FLTK version (1.3.x?) you downloaded.

Comment: Please show us also your error message when you try to build FLTK (if there is one). Please copy-and-paste the text into your message, don't post images (screenshots).

Comment: sir I installed fltk 1.3.5 and I cannot find the build option in VS and my vs version is 1.74.1